# Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, python, include, cmake, kdevelop

I recently installed KDevelop 4 for C++ development on my Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I want to embed Python application in my C++ code. To do that, one needs to include the `Python.h` header file. So, I did that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

However, on running, I received the following response from the IDE:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have `python-dev` package installed.

So, I thought it must be an issue with the header file not being included by KDevelop. Thus, I added the relevant folder to the include path and KDevelop immediately recognized that by removing the red underline beneath the second include statement in the code above.

But still, the problem remains. I get the same error. Would appreciate any help or inputs you guys can provide :-)

(KDevelop is using CMake for my project.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097339/missing-python-h-while-trying-to-compile-a-c-extension-module

Comment: @ddzialak - Yes, I had a look at that question before asking this one. The reason that question didn't help me is that my Python.h file is actually present at /usr/include/python2.7. I manually checked it and when I click on Python.h in the editor, it opens the file.

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal can you help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577539/how-can-i-incorporate-cmake-file-when-building-with-distutils-python

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In your CMakeLists.txt, try adding the following:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(<your exe or lib> ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

For details of the commands, run:

```
cmake --help-module FindPythonLibs
cmake --help-command find_package
cmake --help-command include_directories
cmake --help-command target_link_libraries
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked. Actually, I had got it to work before seeing your answer and after a lot of reading up on CMake, but the solution is the same :D

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal Nice one.  In fact looking at your CMakeLists.txt made me notice that I forgot a set of braces in my original answer!  Fixed now.

Comment: @Fraser I have a similar question. Can you please help me with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577539/how-can-i-incorporate-cmake-file-when-building-with-distutils-python

Comment: How about `--ldflags`?

Comment: @Fraser i have multiple `CMakeLists.txt` so where should i change it??

Comment: `find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)` does not work for me, instead, the new doc of CMake suggests using `find_package(Python COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)` and it works for me

Answer (score 63):

```
sudo apt-get install pythonX.X-dev
```

For example for 3.8

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

*Thank you Cristianjs19 for the comment.*

Original Answer:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

worked for me on a "Python.h: No such file or directory" issue

Comment: Here is what helped me in CentOS: `sudo yum search python` to find proper -devel package, then `sudo yum install python26-devel.x86_64` for my specific version of Python.

Comment: sudo apt-get install pythonX.X-dev (my version X.X) just in case...

Comment: How about windows user please

Answer (score 15):

You want to include the following on the compile line:

```
`python-config --cflags`
```

and this on the link line:

```
`python-config --ldflags`
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am being a noob here but could you please elaborate on what you mean by the compile line and link line in this case? Since I am using the IDE, I am not compiling and linking on the terminal.

Comment: Your IDE has settings somewhere for include paths, library paths, and compiler and linker flags. Run the commands above - the first one gives you `-I` directives (include paths) and compiler flags, the second one does the same for linker. Put those into appropriate settings in you IDE.

Comment: Hmm...KDevelop is using cmake for my project. But I have never used cmake before and would appreciate some help in setting the paths there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no help with those. The bestI can is to refer you to http://userbase.kde.org/KDevelop4/Manual/Building_%28compiling%29_projects_with_custom_Makefiles

Comment: This helped me on Fedora 27.  `python-config` was not installed but Fedora knew about the command and asked if I wanted to install it.  After installing it also installed `Python.h`!   The packages which solved both needs are `python2-devel` and some RPM-related packages (`python-rpm-macros`, `python2-rpm-macros`, and `python3-rpm-generators`).

Answer (score 6):

Most likely `Python.h` is not in your build systems' include path. You can find out where your Python.h is by running

```
dpkg -L python-dev | grep Python.h
```

This will also verify that the python-dev package actually installed a Python.h.

I don't have a kdevelop here, but most IDEs have a setting somewhere where you can specify the include path used by the build system, and you should be able to add the path where Python.h lies there.

EDIT:

As Nikolai implied, you will also need to add the correct library path for the linking stage. (Output of python-config --ldflags).

Comment: I have confirmed that python-dev package did install the Python.h files. The problem is I don't know where or how to add the correct library paths in cmake. Would appreciate any help on that front. I am a complete beginner in cmake. The first time I heard the term was after posting this question.

Answer (score 5):

For Linux Ubuntu Putty Users try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

then compile it

```
gcc -o check xyz.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7
```

then run it

```
./check
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume that it is already installed. Find the path with:

```
find / -iname python.h
```

and when you have done so, when compiling add

```
-I python_h_path
```