# checking for Python.h... no Why does this happen when I know where Python.h is?

Tags: python, sbml

I am running Python through Cygwin on my windows machine. I need to install libSBML in order to use a statistical program (abc-sysbio). The program instructions say:

Download and install libSBML 
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sbml/libsbml/4.0.1/libsbml-4.0.1-src.zip, unzip libsbml-4.0.1-src.zip

```
cd libsbml-4.0.1    

./configure --with-python=<dir> --prefix=<dir> --with-swig=<dir>

make 

make install
```

The download and unzipping were successful, but the command `./configure --with-python=<dir> --prefix=<dir> --with-swig=<dir>` fails due to

```
la-esrnai@SLC-76B7B8A7 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libsbml-4.0.1
$ ./configure --with-python=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/ --  prefix=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/ --with-swig=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe option to reload object  files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking for as... as
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT
checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports  shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports  shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT
checking if g++ PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports  shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
(cached) (cached) checking how to hardcode library paths into programs...    immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gfortran option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT
checking if gfortran PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT works... yes
checking if gfortran static flag -static works... no
checking if gfortran supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gfortran linker (/usr/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe)  supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
(cached) (cached) checking how to hardcode library paths into programs...    immediate
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for bash... /usr/bin/bash
checking if dolt supports this host... yes, replacing libtool
checking for autoconf... autoconf
checking for aclocal... aclocal
checking whether -Wno-long-double is supported... yes
checking for swig... /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/swig
checking /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/swig version >= 1.3.39... yes (found  2.0.12)
checking for python... /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/python
checking for Python prefix... /cygdrive/c/cygwin64
checking for Python.h... no
configure: error: *** /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/include/python2.7/Python.h  missing - please install first or check config.log ***
```

Does anyone know how to rectify this problem given that I can find `Python.h` in my directory?

Have I got the directory wrong in the `./configure --with-python=<dir> --prefix=<dir> --with-swig=<dir>` command?

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: [Missing Python.h while trying to compile a C extension module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4097339)

Comment: Thanks, I have read that page and am unable to progress. Would you be able to explain those instructions in the context of my question please?

Comment: so its not in `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/include/python2.7`? you could install the cygwin python-devel ... that should install it where it expects it to be

Comment: Python.h is in `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/python2.7`. I ran `setup-x86_64.exe` but couldn't find any 'python-dev' or 'python-devel' packages to install

Comment: What would I type instead of `hellomodule.c` in Martijn Pieters' link?