# How to enable Bash in Windows 10 developer preview?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using windows 10 developer preview Build 14295. From the Build conference I understood that we can enable bash in windows 10. But its not clear how to enable bash in windows 10.

Please find below the blog post for running bash in windows 10. 
Link : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx

> After turning on Developer Mode in Windows Settings and adding the
>   Feature, run you bash and are prompted to get Ubuntu on Windows from
>   Canonical via the Windows Store

[image]

I enabled the developer mode. But I am not sure how to add a feature and run the bash. Kindly help.

Comment: Just run `bash` from the command prompt.

Comment: @kaylum I ran the bash. Error screen is attached http://i.stack.imgur.com/pUGqp.png

Comment: Try "Turn Windows features on or off", under "Programs and Features" in Control Panel.

Comment: ... but from what I can see on the web, it looks like the "anniversary update" containing this new feature hasn't been released yet?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Its an anniversary update. But I thought its included in insider preview

Comment: this feature is not part of the Build 14295 it will come later for Insiders

Comment: Albeit remotely related to programming, I'd still say this sounds like a question to post in [Super User](http://superuser.com) instead of SO.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

To enable bash in **Windows 10**:

1. Click the Start button , click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.
2. Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux
3. To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt and type “bash”

[image: Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux]
[image: Installing Ubuntu on Windows using windows store]
[image: Start Bash]

For More Information visit :

1. [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 14316](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/)
2. [Run Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/)

In some cases, attempting to turn on Developer Mode on may crash the Settings app. If this happens, the workaround is to use these steps here to [enable Developer Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development)

Comment: After enabling the developer mode, I don't see the **Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)** option on windows features. My OS build is 10586.164 and its a Win 10 pro. Am i missing something?

Comment: @iamprem the op said `14316` version required.

Comment: I signed up for insider previews and set it to fast ring. But still i don't get the latest build 14316 on checking windows updates. I also checked the registry settings and it looks fine. How long would it take usually to get the updates.

Comment: I have 14316.rs1_release, Developer Mode is on, and `Windows Process Activation Service` is the last item in Features. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Same here, running 14316. dev mode was enabled. re-enabled it again. Still no subsystem entry. Have dutch version. Perhaps localization issue?

Comment: @iamprem you likely use the 32Bt Windows 10 preview, which doesn't support the Lihux System. You need the 64Bit preview

Comment: When is this expected to come to the normal build approximately?

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 that was exactly my problem - my VM was 32 bit, so no Linux Subsystem.

Comment: I have build 10586.318 but system info says that it is a 64-bit operating system. Can I upgrade to 14316 in a way or does that not make sense? Is this build just inferior without the possibility to upgrade?

Comment: For those whom the `Windows Subsystem for Linux(beta)` didn't show up on `Windows Features` window, I installed it by this powerShell command line: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` (source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

Answer (score 19):

The Bash feature isn't available on build 14295.

- Scott answered a question that an update will be coming soon to insiders (Microsoft want to make sure everything is OK with this feature before pushing it to Insiders)
- I've been chatting with a Microsoft Program Manager (Sarah Cooley) and she confirm that she have the Bash feature on Build 14311 (which isn't out for insiders yet)

You can see Scott's answer here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11394994.

Answer (score 1):

Today it is available at Build 14316!
The announcement is at https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/06/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14316/

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Enable Developer Mode (Settings - Update & security > For developers)

Step2: Search for “Windows Features” and choose “Turn Windows features on or off” and enable Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta).

Step3: To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt and type “bash”

Step4: Bash will install required packages on windows you can start with windows bash

Step5: Install any package through apt-get install package_name

Happy Bash programming on windows!

Comment: What is the added value of this answer, compared to other existing answers? E.g. the high-rated and ancient answer by NIthin K Anil.

Comment: @Yunnosch The 'turn features on/off' isn't available by default. Also, searching via start menu is faster then the click progression provided by the accepted answer. Finally, the note about being able to use apt-get from that point has value.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you don´t have to enable developer mode anymore, to run bash. Better security for you without having the dev. mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

download git bash to run bash commands on your windows file system

[git-bash website](https://git-scm.com/downloads)