# XAMPP SERVER mysql not starting "Attempting to start mysql"

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I tried to change the port also and I did it but it is showing me the same message.
"Attempting to start mysql" and a pop up windows is coming regarding net solution to start.
Apache port changed: 80 -->81 
Mysql port changed: 3306-->3307
Earlier i had mysql already, but i uninstalled it. Then also same message is popped up.
Please give the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xampp MySQL not starting - "Attempting to start MySQL service..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279442/xampp-mysql-not-starting-attempting-to-start-mysql-service)

Comment: since you've mentioned xampp, I'd assume it's a windows computer, if it's windows computer, go ahead and enable linux subsystem for windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352627/how-to-enable-bash-in-windows-10-developer-preview then open bash using admin previleges, then run "sudo apt-get install lamp-server^", it should do everything for you :) (at least it does in my ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

Change the MySQL port from 3306 to 3307 or something.

http://silentlyrun.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-change-apache-n-mysql-port-for.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried all the possible ways suggested, but its not working same error!

Comment: @seyyed mahdi mousavi, don't post the answer which is exact copy of the other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31651095/5180017).